# How to properly get available cameras

Tags: flutter

So I've been trying a couple of different solutions but none seem to actually work. I am trying to create a selfie function that also has some overlay.

I am using fluro to route to the selfie screen I created where I want to use the camera.

I've tried multiple ways like `setState(() {});` and the methods below.
But I don't seem to get any cameras. If I try the demp application that comes with the `camera` package and it works perfectly fine.

I just don't see how to get the available cameras in a separate component file. There is still a way to get the cameras during the app initialisation and pass the cameras all the way from the app constructor to the component I need it at. But that seems like a bad practice.

Does anyone have a better method.

This is my `selfie_component.dart` file

```dart
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SelfiePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new SelfiePageState();
}

class SelfiePageState extends State<SelfiePage> {
  CameraController _camera;
  CameraLensDirection _direction = CameraLensDirection.back;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<CameraDescription> _getCamera(CameraLensDirection dir) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
            (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == dir,
          ),
    );
  }

  void _initializeCamera() async {
    _camera = CameraController(
      await _getCamera(_direction),
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    print(_camera);
    await _camera.initialize();
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display the preview from the camera (or a message if the preview is not available).
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (_camera == null || !_camera.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Tap a camera',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 24.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _camera.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(_camera),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my issue.

I have made a seperate `selfie_camara_widget.dart` file

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SelfieCameraWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static SelfieCameraWidgetState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<SelfieCameraWidgetState>());

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new SelfieCameraWidgetState();
}

class SelfieCameraWidgetState extends State<SelfieCameraWidget> {
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  CameraController controller;
  bool isReady = false;
  bool noCameraDevice = false;
  int selectedCamera = 1;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _setupCamera() async {
    try {
      // initialize cameras.
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      // initialize camera controllers.
      controller = new CameraController(
          cameras[selectedCamera], ResolutionPreset.medium
      );

      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (_) {
      debugPrint("Some error occured!");
    }

    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      isReady = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return new Container();
    }
    return new AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: new CameraPreview(controller));
  }

  String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void showInSnackBar(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(message)));
  }

  void logError(String code, String message) =>
      print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');

  void toggleCamera(){
    setState(() {
      selectedCamera = (selectedCamera == 1) ? 0: 1;
      _setupCamera();
    });
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      showInSnackBar('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/trekker_trek';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
    showInSnackBar('Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}');
  }
}
```

Then import it on the correct screen and call `SelfieCameraWidget()`